# Pass all params forward with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can you pass all your params forward with a form_tag?

I've tried:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "users", :action => "index", :params => params) %>

<%= form_tag(:controller => "users", :action => "index", :params => params.except(:controller, :action)) %>
```

How should this work?

Comment: I don't have time to look any further, but I found this post that may be of use.  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/112814

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The helpers know that `:params` is special, so they won't let you set it.  Any other name will work fine...

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "users", :action => "index", :p => params.except(:controller, :action)) %>
```

#### Update

Did you realize that even if you were able to set `:params` that it wouldn't overlay on top of your `params` hash in your controller?  It would have been `params[:params]` in your next request.

It has only just occurred to me that you might have been trying to do this...

```
<%= form_tag( params.merge( :controller => "users", :action => "index" )) %>
```

Comment: that last part is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why my params are getting ignored in the params.merge? If I try the first option I only see the controller and action params sent, yet my controller gets my other params no problem.

Comment: What's the HTML that's generated?